# How do I modify items in a service before returning it back to angular client?

Tags: javascript, angular-httpclient

When returning data from my data-access service I only get undefined after modifiying the response. What is wrong with my pipe?

```
.pipe(
  map(result => result['dimensions']),
  map(result => result.forEach(element => {
    result.dimensionItems = element.dimensionItems.map(item => {
      item.parentId = result.dimensionId;
      item.dimensionItemId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    });
  })),
  tap(result => console.log('Aiiiaiiii: ', result)),
  catchError(this.handleError)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `forEach` returns undefined [1], so you'll need to change your code to this:

```js
.pipe(
  map(result => result['dimensions']),
  map(result => {
    result.forEach(element => {
      result.dimensionItems = element.dimensionItems.map(item => {
        item.parentId = result.dimensionId;
        item.dimensionItemId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
      });
    });
    return result; // You need to return the result after the foreach.
  }),
  tap(result => console.log('Aiiiaiiii: ', result)),
  catchError(this.handleError)
);
```

As you can see from the comment, you need to return the result after you have manipulated it with the `forEach`.

References
[1] - Array.prototype.forEach() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach